# Internetworking devices

Tags: switch, ethernet, bridge

Are hub and repeaters the same? And the same applies for switched and bridges? Since I am finding hub/repeaters and switch/bridge in some books while hubs/switch in others. Also in which layers do they operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Ethernet Repeater** extends the usable range of ethernet cabling so it is not the same as a hub. This is a layer 1 device. You might be getting confused with the name "Repeater" and the function of a hub. Or you could be referring to **Multiport Repeater** which is just another name for a **Hub** function.

A **Hub** is also a layer 1 device. It repeats data out from a source port out every other port. Collision is heavy on a hub.

**Bridges** are layer 2 devices. They exist to physically seperate LAN segments. One of the only decisions a bridge makes is whether to forward or drop a frame. They are different than a **switch** as a **switch** can separate LAN segments on the same hardware using VLANs.**Switches** generally consist of a multitude of ports, while a bridge may only have one.

Comment: hub and repeater are functionally identical. switch and bridge are functional identical. Repeater and bridge are *old* words. (and in fact, a hub is a defunct thing today, too) And a bridge will **always** have two, or more, ports -- a single port would have nothing to bridge as the tech predates VLANs.